# What is the best way to build app architecture( activities and fragments)

Tags: android

I am building app right now. I am trying to follow all design patterns and google suggestions for building responsive apps.
Firstly, my app will contain navigation drawer.Of course my app will have several activities. So I have searched the best way to have navigation drawer on all activities, I found that the most correct way is to use some BaseActivity class which will have navigation drawer in its layout and framelaout for storing each activity representation(container for fragment). It can hold fragment, but the problem is that only one fragment.

So I have faced this problem. I am going to design following activity

[image]

So as in the picture I wanna to have image slider at the top , and some other layout parts under this slider for example grid layout, list or something other.

I think it would be better to separate image slider and other part, for example when my scree will be in landscape orientation it should be replaced but something other.

Futhermore others activites also gonna to have several independent parts for example list and anything other widget.

But as far as my activities should extend BaseActivity class, they would have only one place(container) for storing fragment.

I have tried to think about ways to solve this problem , and I have only one idea is to create several fram layouts in base activity(equal to max fragments used on child activities) and setting them visible and invisible depending on needs, but this approach pretended to be only way of hidding problem.

I don't know what is the most correct way to implement such type of application, so I need help or advices from more experienced developers to build my app correctly and bring user good experience.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the container in your `BaseActivity` does **not** have to necessarily be a `FrameLayout`. For example it could easily be a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`, so that all fragments you add in it will stack one below the other.

Also each fragment can has other nested fragments in itself (although that's generally not the best practice, as usually it indicates some bad UX decisions).

Both those said, I think you just use the first point I made here. Now if you choose this one, I'd expect the question how to handle tablets and other big screens? Best way to handle them is to create a new landscape layout for your `BaseActivity`, where the fragments container might be different, for example a `RelativeLayout`, a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"` and so on.

Good luck!

Comment: luck and programming do not get along.

Comment: Wrong word here ... luck in the sense that this (or some other answer) will help him/her get a better understanding of the problem :)

Comment: hehehe, okay mate ! indeed !